# Errors using LibSerial

Tags: g++, linker-errors, libserial

I have build some code using LibSerial but when i compile it i have this error messages:

```
/tmp/ccUpE4te.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::Open(std::string, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
test.c:(.text+0xbf): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::SetBaudRate(LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::BaudRateEnum)'
test.c:(.text+0xd3): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::SetCharSize(LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::CharSizeEnum)'
test.c:(.text+0xe7): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::SetNumOfStopBits(short)'
test.c:(.text+0xfb): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::SetFlowControl(LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::FlowControlEnum)'
test.c:(.text+0x10f): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::SetVTime(short)'
test.c:(.text+0x123): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::SetVMin(short)'
test.c:(.text+0x1a1): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::Open(std::string, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
test.c:(.text+0x1d3): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::SetBaudRate(LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::BaudRateEnum)'
test.c:(.text+0x1e7): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::SetCharSize(LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::CharSizeEnum)'
test.c:(.text+0x1fb): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::SetNumOfStopBits(short)'
test.c:(.text+0x20f): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::SetFlowControl(LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::FlowControlEnum)'
test.c:(.text+0x223): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::SetVTime(short)'
test.c:(.text+0x237): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStream::SetVMin(short)'
/tmp/ccUpE4te.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[_ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE]+0x48): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::showmanyc()'
/tmp/ccUpE4te.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[_ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE]+0x50): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::xsgetn(char*, long)'
/tmp/ccUpE4te.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[_ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE]+0x58): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::underflow()'
/tmp/ccUpE4te.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[_ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE]+0x68): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::pbackfail(int)'
/tmp/ccUpE4te.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[_ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE]+0x70): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::xsputn(char const*, long)'
/tmp/ccUpE4te.o:(.rodata._ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE[_ZTVN9LibSerial15SerialStreamBufE]+0x78): undefined reference to `LibSerial::SerialStreamBuf::overflow(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I believe that they are linking errors but i cannot understand how i can solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Solution: "gcc -L/usr/local/lib -lserial test.c"

What this solution means?

gcc doesn't know about the libraries you wish to use. You should tell him.

The gcc flag "-l" is the way telling gcc that you want to link to a library installed on you computer.

In your case you should specify: "-lserial"

Another thing you will need to do is to let g++ know where to find this library.

Assuming you didn't make anything special the libaray will be found under /usr/local/lib and will be named libserial.so

You can tell gcc where you keep your libraries by adding another flag "-L" (it should be -L/usr/local/lib) or you can use the local variable to do so:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH